# How to write a function that takes any std::chrono::duration (1ms, 4s, 7h) and gets the seconds as a float?

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

Even just trying to get started, I get an error with this code:

```
note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'double' against 'long'
```

::

```
#include <numeric>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

// how to write a function that will take any duration and turn it 
//   into a float representation of seconds?
template <class T>
void go(std::chrono::duration<double, T> d) {

    // what I want to do (that may not work because I haven't gotten this far):
    float seconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(d);
}

int main()
{
  go(1ms);
  go(1s);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can only guess at what you're trying to accomplish, and here is my best guess:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

void go(std::chrono::duration<float> d) {
    std::cout << d.count() << '\n';
}

int main()
{
  go(1ms);
  go(1s);
}
```

This outputs:

```
0.001
1
```

Comment: `count` doesn't seem to be very appropriately named. :)

Comment: I have a function that creates at timeout and just wanted to be able to say .timeout(1ms) or timeout(1min).  I didn't realize you could just accept it as a duration<float>.  that makes things so much better not having to use a template.

Comment: Why this works: When a `duration<X>` that isn't `duration<float>` gets passed to `go()`, the compiler tries to convert `duration<X>` to a `duration<float>` using `duration<float>`'s _converting constructors_.  One of `duration`'s converting constructors is templatized to accept any type of duration.  This is used to convert `duration<X>` to `duration<float>`, and everything then works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Cast to float and call count():

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <chrono>

template< class T, class P >
float to_secs(std::chrono::duration< T, P > t)
{
    std::chrono::duration< float > f = t;
    return f.count();
}

int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
    std::cout << to_secs(std::chrono::milliseconds(1)) << std::endl;
    std::cout << to_secs(std::chrono::minutes(1)) << std::endl; 
    std::cout << to_secs(std::chrono::hours(1)) << std::endl;
    // output:
    // 0.001
    // 60
    // 3600
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why you have to templatize the first parameter instead of just saying `float` -- especially in light of how Howard's solution below works.

Answer (score 0):

```
template<typename duration_t> float seconds(const duration_t &d);

template<class Rep, class Period>
float seconds(const std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period> &d)
{
    typedef std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period> duration_t;

    auto one_second=std::chrono::duration_cast<duration_t>
                  (std::chrono::seconds(1)).count();

    if (one_second == 0)
        return d.count() *
          std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>
                (duration_t(1)).count();
    else
        return float(d.count())/one_second;
}
```

Comment: I don't quite follow all the steps you're taking -- is it accounting for something theother solutions (specifically Howard's) don't?